# For almost all $ y\in \mathbb{R} $ it applies $ f(x,y)=0 $ for almost all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $ f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} $ be measureable. It applies to almost all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $ that $ f(x,y)=0 $ for almost all $ y\in \mathbb{R} $. Show that for almost all $ y\in \mathbb{R} $ it applies $ f(x,y)=0 $ for almost all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $.

My idea: By condition it follows at first there exists a zero set $ N_y\in \mathcal{B} $ such that $ f(x,y)=0 $ for all $ y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{N_y} $. Furthermore there exists a zero set $ N_x\in \mathcal{B} $ such that it follows:
$$ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{N_x}\quad \forall y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{N_y}: f(x,y)=0. $$
Then it follows:
$$ \forall y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{N_y}\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{N_x}: f(x,y)=0 $$
which shows the statement.

I'm not sure if this works because I don't see where it is necessary to use that f is measurable.

Comment: You mistranslated the condition. It means that there is a zero set $N_2$ such that for every $y \notin N_2$, *there is a zero set $N_{1,y}$* such that for all $x \notin N_{1,y}$, $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Oh ok. But I have no idea how can I show the statement. In principle I have to show that you can change the roll of x and y by changing the quantifiers.

Comment: Hint: compute the (product) measure of $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\})$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessary have single $N_y$ for all $x$. Consider, for example, $f(x, y) = \mathbb I_{x = y}$.

Take any $n$, consider $X = Y = [-n, n]$ and $$g(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1,& f(x, y) \neq 0 \\ 0\end{cases}$$

Then $g$ is measurable and $\iint\limits_{X \times Y} |g(x,y)|\,d(x,y) \leq 4n^2 < \infty$, so we can apply Fubini's theorem to it:

$$0 = \int_Y 0\, dy = \int_Y \int_X g(x, y)\, dx\,dy = \int_X \int_Y g(x, y)\, dy\,dx$$

Because $\int_Y g(x, y)\, dy$ is non-negative, $\int_X \int_Y g(x, y)\, dy\,dx$ implies $\int_Y g(x, y)\, dy = 0$ for almost all $x$. And because $g(x, y)$ is non-negative, it implies that for almost all $x$ for almost all $y$, $g(x, y) = 0$.